# Setting Div position up on another content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page content which have text in it.
underneath the content, there is a navigator bar, and I would like that whenever I Hover one of the element in the navigator, a div will open up just above the element I have just hovered on, and show some content.

I don't want the  DIV that will pop-up to push any object on the page, I would like it to be, like up on all of the objects on the page.

```
some code since I have to insert code tags if I want to post fiddle
```

here's a fiddle to demonstrate:

[***Click here for fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2U7jB/)

In the fiddle, I want that whenever I hover First, the first-feedback will be shown just above him.

This is pretty much my code, I have just used jQuery to calculate my desired width, but I just can't get the div to be above the div he should be above. I can't just calculate by my eye and say how many pixels because the website is pretty much dynamic, so I need a formula to calculate that for me every time.

If you have any code suggestion, such as relocating the feedback div, please feel free to edit the fiddle!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Okay, I did it the way you specified: http://jsfiddle.net/2U7jB/3/. There are other ways to do it - it depends on your HTML.

**Original Response:** This is close to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/2U7jB/2/

```
.popup {
    display: none;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

<div id="first">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
<div id="third">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>

$('#first, #second, #third').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children('.popup').show();
});
$('#first, #second, #third').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).children('.popup').hide();
});
```

To get what you want, just create two divs inside #first, #second, and #third - the first div for the hidden (popup) content, and the second div for the nav menu / background color.